# CGAL: How can I access vertex colors after loading an .off file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 3d, cgal

Loading .off files is easy:

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>  Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3> SurfaceMesh;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
```

...

```
SurfaceMesh surface;
Polyhedron poly;
std::fstream inputOffFile( "myFile.off" );
inputOffFile >> poly;
CGAL::copy_face_graph( poly, surface);
```

Then, I can iterate the vertex coordinates by:

```
std::vector<float> verts;
for( SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index vi : surface.vertices() )
{
    Point pt = surface.point( vi );
    verts.push_back( pt.x() );
    verts.push_back( pt.y() );
    verts.push_back( pt.z() );
}
```

But how can I access the vertex colors, which were stored in the .off file, too?

EDIT: Probably CGAL::copy_face_graph does not copy the color property, so I guess I need a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the full solution, including an access to face vertices (as needed if you want to render the mesh via OpenGL). Working with SurfaceMesh is the key.

```
...
std::vector<Point> verts;
std::vector<Color> cols;

SurfaceMesh::Property_map<SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index, CGAL::Color> vcolors =
    m_pSurface->property_map<SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index, CGAL::Color >( "v:color" ).first;

bool colorExists = m_pSurface->property_map<SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index, CGAL::Color>( "v:color" ).second;

if( !colorExists ) 
    Error(); 

for( SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index vi : m_pSurface->vertices() )
{
    cols.push_back( vcolors[ vi ] );
    verts.push_back( m_pSurface->point( vi ) );
}

for( SurfaceMesh::Face_index face_index : m_pSurface->faces() )
{
    CGAL::Vertex_around_face_circulator<SurfaceMesh> vcirc( m_pSurface->halfedge( face_index ), *m_pSurface ), done( vcirc );

    signed char count = 0;

    do
    {
        count++;
        uint32_t vertexI = *vcirc++;

        const Point &pt = verts[ vertexI ];
        const Color &col = cols[ vertexI ];

        ...

    } while( vcirc != done );

}
```

Many thanks for helpful comments!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the property maps of your SurfaceMesh. If and only if the OFF file has colors (meaning the first indication is COFF and not OFF on the first line), and there are colors per vertices and not only per face, then your SurfaceMesh will have an internal property map called "v:color". You can access it by calling

```
SurfaceMesh::Property_map<SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index, CGAL::Color> vcolors =
      surface.property_map<SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index, CGAL::Color >("v:color").first;

for( SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index vi : surface.vertices() )
{
    CGAL::Color ci = vcolors[vi];
}
```

If there are colors per face you can access it similarly but by searching for the property map called "f:color". You can check for the existance of a map with surface.property_map<......>(...).second.

Comment: What Maxime wrote holds for CGAL::Surface_mesh and not CGAL::Polyhedron_3

Comment: OMG - most probably CGAL::copy_face_graph does not copy the color property ... ? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I debugged the .off-loading into CGAL Polyhedron itself, and the vertex colors were definitely loaded into some internal structure, but are not existing in the SurfaceMesh... .

Comment: Polyhedron_3 does not have an elegant mechanism to add properties. That's why I suggested to switch to Surface_mesh.   The IO of Polyhedron can parse a file with color but ignored them.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I didn't see the off was loaded into a polyhedron. Why don't you load it directly into the surface ? Because the polyhedron reading function does not read the colors, so they don't even get to the dopy_face_graph() phase.